# This is a token-related issue in the iframe

Tags: javascript, reactjs, iframe, token

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yVWeF.png)

I would like to ask a question regarding iframe tokens.

When you log in to ‘Site A’, the token is saved in local storage.
Afterwards, when you press the ‘Start Class’ button in ‘A’, you will be taken to ‘Site B’.

In 'B', display A as an iframe and use the token saved in local storage on site A.

However, if you just installed Chrome or deleted Local State, it will work normally. To be more specific, if you open the developer tools in 'B' and check the local storage, you will find local storage A and local storage B together. Normal operation means that there is a token in A local storage.

However, at some point, there is a token in the local storage searched on site 'A', but there is no token in local storage A on site 'B'. So classes don't run normally, and it's difficult to identify the reason.

If you have any related knowledge or guesses, please leave a comment!!

I did a lot of searching, including Googling, but couldn't solve the problem.

Comment: `if you open the developer tools in 'B' and check the local storage, you will find local storage A and local storage B together` The only way that is possible is if SiteA and SiteB are hosted on the same domain.

Comment: Although it is a different domain, two local storages are currently visible at the same time. I edit content to show my local storages

Comment: Please note that local storage is configured as a local host for company security.